# What happens if I reset a std::shared_ptr to itself

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

The following program crashes with a bad glibc double free error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class foo {
public:
   foo()
   {
      std::cout << "foo constructed" << std::endl;
   }

   ~foo()
   {
      std::cout << "foo destructed" << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   auto f = std::make_shared< foo >();
   std::cout << "Before reset" << std::endl;
   f.reset( f.get() );
   std::cout << "After reset" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

From this I get the following output (followed by the glibc error):

```
foo constructed
Before reset
foo destructed
After reset
foo destructed
```

So obviously in this case the object is destroyed twice. Once by the reset and once by the `std::shared_ptr` going out of scope. This is actually what I would have expected.

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/) however I find the following text (found at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset ):

> If *this already owns an object and it is the last shared_ptr owning it, the object is destroyed through the owned deleter, unless ptr is a pointer to it.

In my opinion this actually says, that the object should not be destroyed as in my example. Quite surprising, but if the standard says so. Am I somehow misreading this, or is the implementation of `std::shared_ptr` I have available not conforming to the standard?

For those who ask why I am doing this:

I am currently trying to figure out how to temporarily manage bare pointers to objects created by `new` and `new[]`. The idea is to use the `std::shared_ptr::reset()` to replace the deleter with a no-op deleter. The alternative is to wrap the code with a `try { stuff() } catch( ... ) { delete x; throw;}` kind of block.

Comment: `f.reset( f.get() )` Why would you *ever* want to do this? If you have temporary "bare pointers to objects", then you shouldn't *delete them*. You should only delete what you *own*, and you don't own what you get from `shared_ptr::get`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Easy answer: Because cppreference suggested that this would be handled differently than other cases. It seems the information is wrong. I will start a discussion on this at cppreference.

Comment: That only explains why you thought it would work. That doesn't explain why you thought it would be a good idea, whether it works or not. What are you trying to do that you *need* this?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Releasing a pointer from a `std::shared_ptr`, by replacing the deleter. However this does actually work correctly with a `std::unique_ptr` instead, which I can also use at this point.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The actual part went like this: Tried to find a good design for the current problem, looked at cppreference, found something I was not quite able to believe, so I tried it. Now I was trying to figure out who is wrong and who is right.

Comment: "Releasing a pointer from a std::shared_ptr, by replacing the deleter." Yeah, I get that far. My question is *why* you want to do that? What are you doing that you need to do this? How does it make sense to retain a pointer after the point when it *may have been destroyed*? Just because you have one `shared_ptr` instance doesn't mean that someone else doesn't have one. In fact, the fact that it's a `shared_ptr` and not some other kind of smart pointer at least suggests that someone else has a copy somewhere. That's why `shared_ptr` doesn't have a `release` method.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, this probably is the reason why it will not work like this. As I said, I was so surprised by the statement on cppreference, that I forget to think about other problems this could have. So no, this is not a good idea to handle like this. `unique_ptr` is the way to go here and once you choose this, my use case is completely covered by it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specification for that overload of `reset` is given in 20.7.2.2.4 shared_ptr modifiers [util.smartptr.shared.mod], paragraph 3 (from n3290):

> ```
> template<class Y> void reset(Y* p);
> ```
>
> Effects: Equivalent to `shared_ptr(p).swap(*this)`.

As you can see, that `shared_ptr(p)` construction creates a new count with new deleter for that `p`, so nothing good can come off it. It really is the best to think of `std::shared_ptr<T>::get` as strictly an observer, and using it to deal with lifetime management is a telltale sign that there is something wrong going on.

On the other hand, `std::unique_ptr<T>` has `release`, which is exactly what you need when you need to step in and deal with ownership yourself for an instant. Perhaps you can change your design to use `std::unique_ptr<T>`? It's always possible to create a `std::shared_ptr<T>` out of it if you need to, eventually. (Although while the `std::shared_ptr<T>` picks the deleter from the `std::unique_ptr<T>`, you still need special treatment in the array case as you probably want `std::shared_ptr<T*>` from `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.)

Comment: Ok, this is what I would have expected, had I not seen that defintion on cppreference. I will start a discussion there to change it.