# Is it guaranteed that weak_ptr will expire when shared_ptr is reset to the same address that contains?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Is it guaranteed that weak_ptr will expire when shared_ptr is reset to the same address that contains?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int* i = new int(0);
    std::shared_ptr<int> si( i );
    std::weak_ptr<int> wi = si;

    si.reset( i );

    assert( wi.expired() ); // wi.expired() == true (GCC 4.7)
}
```

Or is this the case when the value of `wi.expired()` is not defined?

**EDIT:**

I now modify the question little bit:

Is it guaranteed that `weak_ptr` will expire when `shared_ptr` is reset to the same address, which contained a `shared_ptr` when it was initialized `weak_ptr`?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int* i = new int(0);
    std::shared_ptr<int> si( i );
    std::weak_ptr<int> wi = si;

    si.reset();

    int* j = new int(0); 
    // Suppose that new returns the same address that contains variable i :  
    assert(j == i); 

    si.reset( j );

    assert( wi.expired() ); // wi.expired() == true (GCC 4.7)
}
```

Comment: Related question: [What happens if I reset a std::shared_ptr to itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785656/what-happens-if-i-reset-a-stdshared-ptr-to-itself).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On one side, it actually should. 
On the other side it's not correct to assign the same pointer to two different shared pointers (si-before-reset and si-after-reset). In fact, invoking `si.reset(i)` it happens that:

- the ref-count of `si` drops to 0
- `delete i` is invoked
- the reborn `si` points to `i` again.

so the newly assigned `i` after reset will point to not allocated memory, and `wi` is correctly expired (and will give origin to a segfault when `si` is gone, eventually, trying to delete `i` again).

Good practice is to never reference to the naked pointer after it has been assigned to a shared_ptr.

ANSWER AFTER EDIT:

The same applies there too: the fact that the pointer is the same has nothing to do with shared_ptr and its internal ref-count. This is maybe clearer with an "evil" example. This is wrong:

```
  int *i = new int;

  std::shared_ptr<int> si1(i);
  std::shared_ptr<int> si2(i); // deleting twice i on destruction of si2 - boom!
  std::weak_ptr<int> wi1 = si1;

  si1.reset();
  assert (wi1.expired());      // true
```

this is similar (really the same) of your first example: si1 and si2 are two distinct shared_ptr's (they were si-before-reset and si-after-reset). The fact that `si1` and `si2` (wrongly) point to the same memory has nothing to do with the life of the shared_ptr's and of the connected weak_ptr's.

The absolute value of the `i` pointer is not used to determine the ref-count. For both the shared_ptr's and the weak_ptr's. So yes, it is guaranteed!

In fact, when you need the shared_ptr of an object from inside its class, you need [enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) - If you were using `shared_ptr(this)` instead of [shared_from_this()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) you were getting different shared_ptr's every time - destroying your object as soon as the first of them had gone out of ref-counts.