# Does weak_ptr is always expired after shared_ptr reset?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805006/is-it-guaranteed-that-weak-ptr-will-expire-when-shared-ptr-is-reset-to-the-same) but my example is slightly different.

Here is a very simple example:

```
int main()
{
   auto sp = std::make_shared<T>();
   std::weak_ptr<T> wp = sp;
   sp.reset();
   assert(wp.expired());
}
```

Is it guaranteed that in the above case weak_ptr is always expired after shared_ptr reset ?

Comment: @tobi303 That question asks what happens when you reset a `shared_ptr` with the same object. This question asks what happens when you reset with no object.

Comment: @GuyRT oh thats of course a difference. Overlooked that...close vote retracted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed.  Calling

```
sp.reset();
```

is the equivalent of

```
shared_ptr().swap(*this)
```

Which means that `sp` is now back to a default constructed state.  If we look at `use_count` in the standard we have

> *Returns:* the number of `shared_ptr` objects, `*this` included, that share ownership with `*this`, or `0` when `*this` is *empty*.

And since it is empty, `use_count` is `0` and `expried` will be true as [`expried`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired)

> Checks whether the managed object has already been deleted. Equivalent to `use_count() == 0`.

Comment: I don't understand how `wp` accesses `sp`'s `use_count` method.

Comment: @zoecarver When you create `wp` from `sp`, `wp` gets a link to `sp`'s control block.  That is how it can tell if the pointer it points to is valid or not.

Comment: Then does swapping it changes the variable or the value of the control block pointer?

Comment: @zoecarver IIRC the `sp` keeps the same control block, but the values are set back to the default state.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for all the questions :) but in libc++ the default state of the control block is 0 (or nullptr), so that means it simply loses the reference to the control block, right? Also (from the standard), swap "Exchanges the contents of *this and r." (where r.control_block == nullptr).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `expired()` is equivalent to `use_count()==0`. `use_count()` is defined as returning the number of `shared_ptr` instances sharing the managed object. Once you call `sp.reset()` that number is zero.